# Why is it giving me a compiling error for this CallbackContext?

Tags: unity-game-engine, syntax, user-input

Edit: i have fixed the () for the ondisable and onenable but im still getting a compiling error. the error i was actually able to fix fairly easily on my own. thank you all for your help

Ive been trying to get movement working in unity off and on for about a month and keep hitting a brick wall no matter which tutorial i watch or what i read about. the most common method ive seen is plugging it in manually and making OnMove functions which use InputAction.CallbackContext x
and theres the snag, i have InputSystems in use. and nothing im able to dig up even mentions this as a problem so i have no idea what im doing wrong or how to start fixing it.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.InputSystem;

public class Controls : MonoBehaviour
{
    private PlayerControl control = null;
    private Vector2 move = Vector2.zero;

    private void Awake()
    {
        control = new PlayerControl();
    }

    private void OnEnable()
    {
        control.Enable();
        control.Land.Move.performed += Move;
        control.Land.Move.canceled += MoveEnd;
    }

    private void OnDisable()
    {
        control.Disable();
        control.Land.Move.performed -= Move;
        control.Land.Move.canceled -= MoveEnd;
    }

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Debug.Log(move);
    }

    private void Move(InputAction.CallbackContext context)
    {
        move = context.ReadValue<Vector2>();
    }

    private void MoveEnd(InputAction.CallbackContext callback)
    {
        move = Vector2.zero;
    }
}
```

Comment: You should add the error(s) you're getting to your question.

Comment: you edited away the original error in `OnEnable` ... it is still there as well in `OnDisable` though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have parentheses on your callback functions.

```
control.Land.Move.performed += Move();
control.Land.Move.canceled += MoveEnd();
```

These need to be removed when subscribing and unsubscibing.

```
control.Land.Move.performed += Move;
control.Land.Move.canceled += MoveEnd;
```

Parentheses are used when calling the function.  In the case of events, the event is responsible for the parameters, so parentheses wouldn't make sense (how/why would you pass a callback context instance?).  Along those same lines, there is no function `Move()` defined, but there is a function `Move(CallbackContext ctx)` defined.

Answer (score 0):

The issue with your code is that you are not sending the proper arguments to `Move` nor `MoveEnd` when registering those on the input events

Instead of `control.Land.Move.performed += Move();` it should be `control.Land.Move.performed += Move;` (withouth the `()` in the method signature). This will automatically assign the data sent by the event to the listener method.

You can check more about how C# events work right [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/events/)